# SAS sum observations not in a group, by group

Tags: dataframe, sas

I have a data set :

```
data have;
   input group $ value;
   datalines;
A 4
A 3
A 2
A 1
B 1
C 1
D 2
D 1
E 1
F 1
G 2
G 1
H 1
;
run;
```

The first variable is a group identifier, the second a value.

For each group, I want a new variable "sum" with the sum of all values in the column, exept for the group   the observation is in.

My issue is having to do that on nearly 30 millions of observations, so efficiency matters.
I found that using data step was more efficient than using procs.

The final database should looks like :

```
data want;
   input group $ value $ sum;
   datalines;
A 4 11
A 3 11
A 2 11
A 1 11
B 1 20
C 1 20
D 2 18
D 1 18
E 1 20
F 1 20
G 2 18
G 1 20
H 1 20
;
run;
```

Any idea how to perform this please?

Edit: I don't know if this matter but the example I gave is a simplified version of my issue. In the real case, I have 2 other group variable, thus taking the sum of the whole column and substract the sum in the group is not a viable solution.

Comment: Regarding "I found that using data step was more efficient than using procs." What code did you try ?  How many different groups are there in the 30M rows ?

Comment: It wasn't for this specific task, I was computing count variables for around 60 millions observations, don't remember the proc I used it was two years ago and since i've done similar tasks using data steps.
At the time I began using procs and it was taking at least 2 hours when I could do the same thing with data step in less than 30 minutes.
The issue may be the RAM, computations are made on a server with only 8gb on ram (no possiblility to add more).

Comment: Is the data always presorted by `group` ?

Comment: How would having multiple grouping variables change what you want?  Are you saying you want multiple sum variables in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement

> sum of all values in the column, except for the group the observation is in

indicates two passes of the data must occur:

1. Compute the `all_sum` and each group's `group_sum`
   A hash can store each group's sum -- computed via a specified `suminc:` variable and `.ref()` method invocation. A variable can accumulate `allsum`.
2. Compute `allsum` - `group_sum` for each row of a group.
   The `group_sum` is retrieved from hash and subtracted from `allsum`.

Example:

```
data want;
  if 0 then set have; * prep pdv;

  declare hash sums (suminc:'value');
  sums.defineKey('group');
  sums.defineDone();

  do while (not hash_loaded);
    set have end=hash_loaded;
    sums.ref();                * adds value to internal sum of hash data record;
    allsum + value;
  end;

  do while (not last_have);
    set have end=last_have;
    sums.sum(sum:sum);         * retrieve groups sum. Do you hear the Dragnet theme too?;
    sum = allsum - sum;        * subtract from allsum;
    output;
  end;

  stop;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked perfectly on the minimal example but I'm having trouble using it for multiple groups.
In my case I have 3 levels of groups, first level being years, then areas and finally groups inside areas.

A simple by statement at the beginning of the datastep doesn't work because in the do while loop it's taking the sum for the whole database.

Any idea how to modify your code to allow for more levels of groups please?

Comment: change the `defineKey` statement to list all the group variables, `sums.defineKey('byvar1', 'byvar2', 'byvar3');`

Comment: Of course, more grouping variables means more combinations means more memory needed to hold the hash.  You said 30M observations. Can you answer the questions: About how many by groups ? Are the groups in sorted order ? Do you license SAS/MDDB ? Per @Tom, do you want more than one sum variable (i.e. do you want level-1 aggregate, level-2 aggregate and level-3 aggregate ?)

Comment: Yes the group are sorted. The first group has 9 levels, the second 304 and the last a bit less than 100.
The number of hash to be remembered are only for the last group so around 100.
For SAS/MDDB I have no idea as the licence is purchased by the server and data provider.

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with a straight forward approach?  You need to make two passes no matter what you do.

Like this.  I included extra variables so you can see how the values are derived.

```
proc sql ;
 create table want as
  select a.*,b.grand,sum(value) as total, b.grand - sum(value) as sum
  from have a
     , (select sum(value) as grand from have) b
  group by a.group
 ;
quit;
```

Results:

```
Obs    group    value    grand    total    sum

  1      A        3        21       10      11
  2      A        1        21       10      11
  3      A        2        21       10      11
  4      A        4        21       10      11
  5      B        1        21        1      20
  6      C        1        21        1      20
  7      D        2        21        3      18
  8      D        1        21        3      18
  9      E        1        21        1      20
 10      F        1        21        1      20
 11      G        1        21        3      18
 12      G        2        21        3      18
 13      H        1        21        1      20
```

Note it does not matter what you have as your GROUP BY clause.

Do you really need to output all of the original observations?  Why not just output the summary table?

```
proc sql ;
 create table want as
  select a.group, b.grand - sum(value) as sum
  from have a
     , (select sum(value) as grand from have) b
  group by a.group
 ;
quit;
```

Results

```
Obs    group    total    sum

 1       A        10      11
 2       B         1      20
 3       C         1      20
 4       D         3      18
 5       E         1      20
 6       F         1      20
 7       G         3      18
 8       H         1      20
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach totally works, I just lack experience with sql.

If you have a few more minutes, how would you do to include multiple group in the statement? As you stated "it does not matter what you have as your GROUP BY clause", how could I do to compute this for multiple (3 in my case) levels of groups?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple groups".  If your groups are defined by multiple variables, say AGEGROUP and GENDER then just use both in the GROUP BY statement.  `group by agegroup, gender`.  If you want a separate sums for the different AGEGROUP categories and another set of sums for the GENDER categories ten you will need to do separate analyses.

Answer (score 0):

I would break this out into two different segments:

1.) You could start by using PROC SQL to get the sums by the group

2.) Then use some IF/THEN statements to reassign the values by group